Implement service registry servers with load balancing strategies
Have Implemented below service registry class with 2 load balancing strategies.Used Strategy Pattern. Used Stamped lock ( Optimistic write locking) for ensuring thread safety and concurrency. Used Atomic Integer and ThreadLocalRandom in round robin and random load balancers for concurrency.
Am I missing any important concepts here ? Are there any improvements that can be done to improve performance and thread safety ? What could be some few followup questions/additional implementations that can be asked after implementing this in a live coding interview?
package com.java.learning;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock;
public class LoadBalancer 
{

private static final int MAX_SERVER_ALLOWED = 10;

private final List<String> servers = new ArrayList<>();

private LoadBalancerStrategy loadBalancerStrategy;

private final StampedLock stampedLock = new StampedLock();

public boolean register(List<String> serverInstanceUrls) {

    try {
        long stamp = stampedLock.tryWriteLock();
        if (validate(serverInstanceUrls) && stampedLock.validate(stamp)) {
            servers.addAll(serverInstanceUrls);
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        stampedLock.tryUnlockWrite();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean validate(List<String> serverInstanceUrls) {
    boolean hasDuplicate =  servers.stream().anyMatch(server->
            serverInstanceUrls.stream().anyMatch(incomingServer->incomingServer.equals(server)));
    return !hasDuplicate && servers.size() + serverInstanceUrls.size() <= MAX_SERVER_ALLOWED;

}

public String get()
{
   return loadBalancerStrategy.balanceLoad(servers);
}

public void setLoadBalancerStrategy(LoadBalancerStrategy loadBalancerStrategy) {
    this.loadBalancerStrategy = loadBalancerStrategy;
}
}

  package com.java.learning;
  import java.util.List;
  public interface LoadBalancerStrategy {
   String balanceLoad(List<String> servers);
  }

 package com.java.learning;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
 
 public class RandomLoadBalancer implements LoadBalancerStrategy {

  @Override
  public String balanceLoad(List<String> servers) {
    if (servers != null && !servers.isEmpty()) {
        return servers.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(servers.size()));
    }
    return "";
}
}

package com.java.learning;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class RoundRobinLoadBalancer implements  LoadBalancerStrategy{

 private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

  @Override
  public String balanceLoad(List<String> servers) {
    if(servers!=null && !servers.isEmpty()) {
        int index = counter.getAndIncrement() % servers.size();
        return servers.get(index);
    }
    return "";
}
}



I rolled back the edit.  Do not change the code in the question after receiving an answer. Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.

Locking
If you're using only tryWriteLock(), you don't really benefit from StampedLock. It only causes inconvenience by forcing you validating the stamp it produces.
From its very inception, Lock interface features method Lock.tryLock() that immediately acquires the lock if available without blocking and returns a boolean result.
So, instead of a StampedLock you can use any Lock implementation, and logic inside the register() method will look in the following way:
if (lock.tryLock()) {
    try {
        // critical section
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
return false;

Besides that, your attempt to unlock a lock that might not be acquired is a serious bug, which is already described in the answer by Sara J.
Another issue is that you're not using lock while reading. Which means that if the list of server URLs is being updated at the moment when LoadBalancer.get() is invoked, the new elements of the list would not be taken into account by get().
Just to make things clear, here's what's happens in regard to locking and data visibility on invocation of register() and get().
When register() is called the write lock is being acquired, which establishes a happens-before relationship. And once the lock is released, every thread becomes aware of the changes to the list of URLs. Which otherwise might not be observed at all, since ArrayList is not a concurrent collection.
When get() is invoked without a read lock, the possibility of the URL list being modified at the very same moment is ignored.

If you want the get() method to be able to observe the change that can occur during its execution (and accept that execution of get() might be blocked), you should to use locking inside this method.
And if you wish to so, then can you leverage StemptLock because it allows to avoid blocking at every acquisition of a read lock via StamptLock.tryOptimisticRead(), but calls still might be blocked (if you want the every get() call to succeed).
Unclear URL registration policy
You didn't list the requirements, and it's difficult to infer them from your implementation, since it might register up to 10 new identical URLs, but will reject any list containing at least one previously URL.
If there's a requirement that the whole list should be rejected, then you have to verify that its elements are unique.
Or if the goal is only to ensure that the same URL hasn't been added twice, you can filter distinct URLs from the given list.
Naming and Formatting

The name of the code element should reflect its responsibility.

Hence, variable names should communicate their purpose, not their type.
StampedLock stampedLock is meant to serve as a lock, i.e. to control the execution of critical sections of the code. Therefore, it should be named lock (if you would want to know its type - just hover mouse over it and your IDE will tell it).
Similarly, LoadBalancerStrategy strategy should be named strategy instead.

Try to be concise, but yet clear. It's not obvious for the reader of the code that servers is a collection of URLs, the name serverUrls would communicate the intent better.

Don't skimp on white spaces incomingServer->incomingServer.equals(server)

Using C-style curly braces { } with the opening curly on the next line is against the Java language conventions.

Leverage your IDE to help you out with formatting. For instance, CTRL + ALT + L - is the autoformatting shortcut in IntelliJ.


Refactored version
It's better to provide strategy through constructor than through setter. Because it's always preferable that your constructors are returning a fully initialized ready to go instance rather than something half-baked, that you need to tinker with (otherwise - boom! a NullPointerException).
You can find examples of injecting a strategy through a setter online, but that isn't the best approach for the reasons I laid out above (and sure we do use setters in some real life scenarios, please, don't get me wrong)
public class LoadBalancer {
    private static final int MAX_SERVER_ALLOWED = 10;

    private final Set<String> serverUrls = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private final StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();
    private final LoadBalancerStrategy strategy;
    
    public LoadBalancer(LoadBalancerStrategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
    
    public boolean register(List<String> urlsToRegister) {
        long stamp = lock.tryWriteLock();
        if (lock.validate(stamp)) {
            try {
                return tryRegister(urlsToRegister);
            } finally {
                lock.unlockWrite(stamp);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    private boolean tryRegister(List<String> candidates) {
        if (!canAdd() || candidates.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return serverUrls.addAll(
            filterEligibleServers(candidates)
        );
    }
    
    private boolean canAdd() {
        return serverUrls.size() < MAX_SERVER_ALLOWED;
    }
    
    private List<String> filterEligibleServers(List<String> serverUrls) {
        return serverUrls.stream()
            .distinct()
            .filter(s -> !this.serverUrls.contains(s))
            .limit(MAX_SERVER_ALLOWED - this.serverUrls.size())
            .toList();
    }
    
    public String get() {
        long stamp = lock.tryOptimisticRead();
        var urls = serverUrls;
        
        if (!lock.validate(stamp)) {
            stamp = lock.readLock();
            try {
                urls = serverUrls;
            } finally {
                lock.unlockRead(stamp);
            }
        }
        
        return strategy.balanceLoad(
            urls.stream().toList()
        );
    }
}

The implementation above filters unique URL from the given list rejecting the duplicates.
If the list has to be rejected in case if there are any duplicates, here how it can be done:
private boolean tryRegister(List<String> candidates) {
    if (candidates.isEmpty() ||
        !canAdd(candidates.size()) ||
        !hasNoDuplicates(candidates)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return serverUrls.addAll(candidates);
}

private boolean hasNoDuplicates(List<String> candidates) {
    return allUnique(candidates)
        && candidates.stream().noneMatch(serverUrls::contains);
}

private static boolean allUnique(List<String> candidates) {
    return Set.copyOf(candidates).size() == candidates.size();
}

private boolean canAdd(int toAdd) {
    return serverUrls.size() + toAdd <= MAX_SERVER_ALLOWED;
}



register seems to try and ensure that a server URL is not registered multiple times. However, this still happens the same URL appears multiple times in a single list passed to register. This strikes me as a possible bug.

If not having duplicates is important, it may be worth considering if servers should be a Set instead of a List. If both uniqueness and ordering is important, SequencedSet may be an option.


If another server has successfully caused the lock to be in a write lock state, tryWriteLock will fail, but tryUnlockWrite might not - it may instead unlock the write lock the other thread acquired, possibly allowing a third thread to edit the list while the first one is still doing so. This is almost certainly not desirable. Use unlockWrite instead and pass the stamp.
By passing the internal list to balanceLoad, get allows the strategy to potentially edit the list of servers, without even having to synchronize with any other threads to do so. The usual solution to this would be to copy the list on each invocation. If we expect register calls to be much less frequent than get calls, it could make sense to keep a cached copy of the list instead - if so we may be able to use an optimistic read stamp to check whether the cached copy needs updating.
Currently it is possible to have a LoadBalancer with a null strategy. Such an object is not well-behaved and it may be worth considering whether it should even be possible to construct such an object. If this is not desirable, setLoadBalancerStrategy should check its parameter for null and LoadBalancer's constructor should take a LoadBalancerStrategy as a parameter.
Having the strategies return "" on failure makes it less clear that balancing failed. I would suggest either returning null, changing the return type to Optional<String> and returning Optional.empty(), or throwing some manner of exception.
Various fields are named as though servers are represented by URLs. It may be appropriate to enforce that at the type level by having them represented by URLs instead of Strings. Alternatively, if we want more flexilibity than that we could consider making LoadBalancer and LoadBalancerStrategy generic.
The name setLoadBalancerStrategy feels a tad redundant. Typically it'll be used in statements like myLoadBalancer.setLoadBalancerStrategy(...) or getLoadBalancer().setLoadBalancerStrategy(...), in which case myLoadBalancer.setStrategy(...) and getLoadBalancer().setStrategy(...) would seem to be more concise yet no less clear.


amazing. Thanks a lot for the effort you have made to do this great review. Regarding the duplicate logic , is there a logical error ? please enlighten me how it can be a possible bug ? Suppose Interviewer insists me not to use a Set, how can i still make it correct by using List ?

If we expect register calls to be much less frequent than get calls, it could make sense to keep a cached copy of the list instead ->> suppose register calls are more frequent than get , how can i resolve this bug ?

@Jill 1) Either validate could reject any list where the same URL appears multiple times (checking serverInstanceUrls.stream().distinct().count() == serverInstanceUrls.size() could be one way to do that). Alternatively, the subsequent addAll could be replaced with something that adds each distinct element once (such as serverInstanceUrls.stream().distinct().forEachOrdered(servers::add)). 2) In that case I would probably just have every get call make a new copy with List.copyOf and not worry about caching

Have added the updated code as per all your review comments.Handled get() with optimistic read . added single registry as parameter instead of list. Requesting further suggestions and improvements if any

Handled null strategy inside the constructor with default as Random Load Balancer, returned optional instead of ""
